apt-get update silently fails to resolve repositories in AWS Run Command document
Hello I thought I managed to work around the issue already but seems not to be the case.
When I first noticed the issue that apt-get update can silently fail in Systems Manager Run Command I added the "-o APT::Update::Error-Mode=any" option.
    "runCommand": [
          "sudo apt-get update -o APT::Update::Error-Mode=any",
          "sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confdef\" -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confold\" upgrade -y --autoremove"
        ]

But this does not seem to work for me. I still get this in Run Command logs and no error is indicated anywhere else.

Err:1 https://my-repo.active-fleet.com myapp-bullseye-stable InRelease
Could not resolve 'my-repo.active-fleet.com'

Command status is Success and everything is fine unless you go digging in the logs.
How would I go about getting a reliable failed state for command when the apt-get update fails?
Here is the full code for the Document I am using
{
  "schemaVersion": "2.2",
  "description": "description redacted",
  "parameters": {
    "action": {
      "type": "String",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Reboot",
        "DoNotReboot"
      ]
    }
  },
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "action": "aws:runShellScript",
      "name": "installUpgrades",
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "sudo apt-get update -o APT::Update::Error-Mode=any",
          "sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confdef\" -o Dpkg::Options::=\"--force-confold\" upgrade -y --autoremove"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "action": "aws:runShellScript",
      "name": "rebootXMU",
      "precondition": {
        "StringEquals": [
          "{{ action }}",
          "Reboot"
        ]
      },
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "UPTIME_SECONDS=`awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime`",
          "UPTIME_SECONDS=${UPTIME_SECONDS%.*}",
          "echo \"Uptime: $UPTIME_SECONDS seconds\"",
          "if [ $UPTIME_SECONDS -gt 300 ]; then",
          "echo \"Rebooting since uptime is greater than 5mins ...\"",
          "exit 194",
          "else",
          "echo \"Already rebooted within last 5mins\"",
          "fi"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

